# Median comparisons and population size

Tags: statistics, median

Suppose I have the following data, which corresponds to the median rental price of distinct areas:

```
Area          | Median Rental Price | Nr Houses
Soho          |   $2,500            |   15
Harlem        |   $2,400            |  250
Chelsea       |   $3,500            |    2
East Village  |   $1,500            |   10
```

Basically, this means that for Soho I used 15 houses to calculate the median rental price. I have the individual data for each house in the set, namely the respective rental price.

If I want to compare the distinct areas to see which ones are most expensive/cheap to live is there a formula I can use to ignore an area due to having a smaller population in the data set?

Comment: How about taking the average instead and comparing that?

Comment: Are you worried that the sample median is a poor estimator of the population median because of the small sample size?